# What's equal in jquery ajax to post multiple same name input value of html form?

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax

HTML form like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
    <input type='text' size='30' name='email' value='testing1@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' name='email' value='testing2@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' name='email' value='testing3@gmail.com' />
</form>
```

How can I post the same data to web server in jQuery ajax? The server side using Struts2 to receive parameters.

Comment: Change method to `get` and submit. Then you will see how the url is formed. (Don't forget to change it back to `post` when you're done.)

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks, I have some other doubt, which I make a new questition [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38632315/2205911)